# SSIS 2016 How to Pass UNC Path plus GETDATE() to ConnectionString Property of Flat File Connection Manager?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2016 to run a query from SQL Server 2016 and create a text file with the query results onto a network share.  I cannot use a drive letter in the path and therefore use a UNC path instead.  My original approach was to pass an expression into the Flat File Connection Manager ConnectionString property but the package fails with errors after deployment to Integration Services catalog.

So, I created a parameter that stores the Connection String as a string in the following format:

```
\\UNCPath\dir1\dir2\dir3(has spaces)\dir4\dir5\dir6\dir7\dir8\Filename_+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4,   
1252)DATEPART("yyyy", getdate() ),4)  +  RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("mm", getdate() ), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" +(DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("dd",getdate() ), 2) + .txt
```

Note that I need to include GETDATE() in yyyymmdd format at the end of the file name.

I receive an error when I try to run the package stating:

```
The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.The 
file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
```

What changes are needed to ensure a valid path and filename are passed by my parameter?

Comment: Try using `CONVERT(char(8), getDate(), 112)`

Comment: An actual SSIS Parameter or an SSIS Variable?

Comment: @billinkc I created an SSIS Parameter.

Comment: @Xabi Unfortunately, this did not work.  When I remove the quotation marks from the parameter and use your suggestion, the package succeeds but literally adds your code to the filename.  When I add back the quotation marks, SSIS complains that it's an invalid filename.

Comment: Xabi's approach is valid if you were in TSQL but this is the SSIS expression language which is its own beast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My forever advice with the SSIS expression language is to make it easier on yourself.

Never modify an expression on an object directly. There is no way to debug what the expression is and you're left guessing as to what went wrong.

Instead, create lots of SSIS variables in the package. They're "free" to use and are your only hope for identifying what went into the black box of a task.

In your case, I'd envision at least 5 variables.

- FileBase - String - Filename_
- FileExtension - String - .txt
- FolderBase - String - \Server\Share...\dir8\
- CurrentDate - String - Evaluate as exprexsion = True - `RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("yyyy", getdate() ),4)  +  RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("mm", getdate() ), 2) + RIGHT("0" +(DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("dd",getdate() ), 2)`

FileBase is just the word "Filename_"

FileExtension is ".txt"

FolderBase should look exactly as we defined, no backslash escapes required but it must have the trailing slash

CurrentDate should look like YYYYMMDD which would be 20200925 as of this posting

Putting all of that together would yield what we want but back to rule #1, don't do it all in the ConnectionString of property. Instead, add your final SSIS Variable

- CurrentFileName - string - Evaluate as expression = True - `@[User::FolderBase] + @[User::FileBase] + @[User::CurrentDate] + @[User::FileExtension]`

Now we're cooking! When you open the package up, you can see whether that path looks correct. You can add a Script Task to the start of the package to [force the variable values to show up in the SSISDB log](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) (although the non-dynamic parts will already be there).

In the comments, you indicated you were using Parameters. They're a little different in that they are read only and to my knowledge, don't support expressions so the above formula is still valid with just a little tweak.

Create a Parameter that corresponds to each Variable that you want to make dynamic. i.e. UNC path changes as the package migrates from local environment to dev to uat to production server.

Ensure the Parameters match what the Variables had -aka trailing slash on the path for UNC.

Modify the Variable(s) to now have EvaluateAsExpression = True and then align the expression to the parameter

- FolderBase - String - Evaulate as expression = true - `@[$PackageName::FolderBase]`

The only two variables you can't have

Now that everything is good and works as expected, then use @[User::CurrentFileName] to drive the flat file connection manager.

Comment: You should offer a training course with your answers!